# Swing: JPanel "setSize" is ignored?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

So in my program, the buttonPanel.setSize does not seem to be working:

```
public class View extends JFrame {

private JButton[] button = new JButton[16];
private JPanel buttonPanel;

public View() {
    super();
    init();
}

public void init() {
    setTitle("Memory-Game");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(750, 500);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));
    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        button[x] = new JButton();
        buttonPanel.add(button[x]);
    }
    buttonPanel.setSize(315, 315);
    getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new View();
}
```

While the JFrame size is 750x500, I want the buttonPanel to only take up space of 315x315 in the center. 
However, the buttonPanel stretches itself across the whole JFrame.

```
buttonPanel.setSize(315, 315);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the buttonPanel stretches itself across the whole JFrame.

Correct. That is the rule of the BorderLayout. Any component added to the CENTER will take all the space available in the frame.

And the GridLayout will also grow to take all the available space.

> I want the buttonPanel to only take up space of 315x315 in the center.

Don't try to specify pixel sizes. That is not the way layout management works.

The easiest way to center a component in the frame is to use the `GridBagLayout`:

```
//getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // remove
...
//getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // remove
setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
add(buttonPanel, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Now each button will be set to its preferred size and the panel will be sized to contain all the buttons.

If you want extra space for the buttons then you use a property like:

```
button[x].setMargin( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Mangers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information on each layout manager and working examples.

Edit:

> the JFrame is set to a specific size and non-resizable. Is there a way to do it with pixels regardless

Forget about the frame. That is NOT how you use Swing. The size of components can be different on each LAF. For example the Font used can be different. The size of the title bar or border of the frame can be different. Don't attempt to set the size of the frame. You give "hints" for each component and let each component determine its size. Then you `pack()` the frame and the frame will become the size of the child components.

So for example for the buttons you can do:

```
button.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(50, 50) );
```

So if you have 4 button in a grid, the size of the panel will be (200 x 200).

If you want extra space on the panel you can do:

```
panel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(200, 200, 200, 200) );
```

which will reserve extra space to the size of the panel including the buttons now becomes (400 x 400).

Then when you `pack()` the frame the frame size will be (600 x 600) plus the size of the title bar and borders.

Read the tutorial! There is also a section on `How to Use Borders`.

Comment: Gotcha thanks. However in my specific application the JFrame is set to a specific size and non-resizable. Is there a way to do it with pixels regardless?

Comment: @Dave that is NOT the way you design an application. See edit.